# React.js : How to run react.js code in two ports.? each component in one port

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to run react.js code in two localhost ports like one "component1.js" has to run on localhost:3000 port and second "component2.js" has to run on localhost:3001 port  using the same React.js application
please find the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l02P.png)attachment.

Comment: You will need to be more specific. React is not an HTTP server. What do you intend to use to serve your React app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your app on two ports:

```
npm run dev -- -p 3000
```

And for the second:

```
npm run dev -- -p 3001
```

Then get the port number and redirect to the desired component.

Comment: No, when we enter https://localhost:3000 it has to only appear component1.js
For component2 if you enter localhost:3001 it has to appear only component2.js

Comment: Yes, you need to add some logic. So, in your app.js file get the port number from the request and redirect to the desired component according to the port number..

Answer (score 0):

My solution: a custom node application which starts 2 http servers on 2 ports, with each one serving a component.js file.